# how to change Sales order default status? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-status

In my website if order has placed via paypal or anything the status is seted as **processing**, but i like to set status to be **pending**. How to set, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the list of predefined order statuses, go to

```
Stores -> Order Status
```

You’ll see all the existing statutes in the store

Set the 'Default Status' filter to 'Yes' to show only the default statuses.

You can set any of your status to while assigning **status to state**

Reference: https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/magento-2-order-status/

Comment: Here are my status list http://prntscr.com/o6dwhc

Comment: The default status is 'processing' do you want to assign a new status in default?

Comment: I like to set default status to be "pending"

Comment: It is already set to default. Can you verify by placing cash on delivery order and check what you are getting in status

Comment: If it is COD the status is pending, but if order is paid option the status set as "processing"

Comment: then it would be set in your payment method that when ever any order received then order will be marked on processing.

Comment: It's been in backend or in files?

Comment: could be either in system configuration or in code

Comment: Thank you, let me check

Answer (score 4):

For this You need to create new status and assign it to State go to admin panel Stores > Settings > Order Status create YOUR NEW STATUS after that go to "Assign Status to State", here select YOUR NEW STATUS and Set Order State "Pending" now save it .

so now when you will create new order then order status will be pending . after that you can view and changed it YOUR NEW STATUS

[Reference](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-order-status-order-state.html)

Reference 2[enter link description here](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/manage-order-status-in-magento-2/)

Create order status like below

[image]

Comment: Here are my status list http://prntscr.com/o6dwhc

Comment: I have update code. plz review it

Comment: Your answer is also good. +1 for that :)

Comment: Hi, i created new status and assign it "http://prntscr.com/o7wlpg" but i didn't view in sales list. "http://prntscr.com/o7wmqy", Because i need to send email after delivered

Comment: @Priya - have you found the solution? I am looking for a similar solution. By default, I wanted to see the status "Pending". Kindly share the details.

Comment: @vinayagam, I followed with Shorabh's answer. That was well cleared answer for me. If you select COD option you must need to select "sales->payment method->http://prntscr.com/qmz941.. For other online payment default set as "processing" only.